# Why does this makefile fails when I remove the vpath directive?

Tags: c, gcc, gnu-make

I am playing around with GNU GCC makefiles, and made this simple one to build a "Hello, world!" program.

```
CC=gcc
SOURCES=./Source/main.c
BUILD_DIR=./Build
TARGET=main

all: $(BUILD_DIR)/$(TARGET).exe

OBJECTS = $(addprefix $(BUILD_DIR)/,$(notdir $(SOURCES:.c=.o)))
vpath %.c $(sort $(dir $(SOURCES)))

$(BUILD_DIR)/%.o: %.c
    $(CC) -c $< -o $@

$(BUILD_DIR)/%.exe: $(OBJECTS)
    $(CC) $< -o $@
```

I cannot understand why when I remove or comment this line
`vpath %.c $(sort $(dir $(SOURCES)))`, make stops and returns this error:

```
> Executing task: D:\Servers\Compilers\MinGW\bin\mingw32-make.exe GCC_PATH=D:\Servers\Compilers\gcc-arm-none-eabi\bin <

mingw32-make: *** No rule to make target 'Build/main.exe', needed by 'all'.  Stop.
```

Could you please explain me why?

Comment: Pass `--debug` to `make` to see more info.

Comment: I've done that, but still found no useful information

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You added the prefix to the object file so your OBJECTS is './Build/main.o'.
But when you use the static rule,the '.o' postfix would be replaced by '.c',so your OBJECTS is ./Build/main.c.Your main.c is not in the directory "Build",so it certainly failed.When you add `vpath %.c $(sort $(dir $(SOURCES)))`,it will automatically find the `.c` file out of the directory `Build`.

Comment: This is _almost_ correct.  But make would never look in `Build`; the pattern you have is `$(BUILDDIR)/%.o : %.c`.  If `BUILDDIR` is `Build` then when make is trying to build a target `Build/foo.o` the prerequisite is `foo.c` (not `Build/foo.c`).  The rest is as you say: `foo.c` doesn't exist so you need to use `vpath` to tell make where to look for it.

Comment: Thanks you guys very much! I didn't notice about that